# How do you achieve this look and what style is it called?

Tags: photoshop, contrast

[image: Desaturated look?]

I'm not sure how to describe the look in the picture, but I would like to achieve. Can anyone explain the specifics of it? I don't know where to start although it does look a bit desaturated.

Comment: Can you try a little harder to describe the part that you're asking about? Are you interested in the Urban Blizzard aesthetic? The Potential Unrequited Love composition? Contrasty Outerwear? Low-flying Cloud? Could you at least provide more examples? There are many attributes of the photo that someone might call "this look", but which are different from what  you're looking at.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for "high-key lighting", although this photo isn't quite there.

Comment: Please read [Important information for asking "What's this effect?" questions](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/important-information-for-asking-whats-this-effect-questions) and edit this post accordingly. Make sure to use a descriptive title, too. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Cloudy wintertime lighting produces a cooler, lower-contrast, lower-saturation image by nature compared to other times of the year. You can achieve this by shooting at that time of year and under cloudy conditions.

If shooting digitally, you should shoot in Raw mode to gain more control in post-processing. Even though you'll have the ability to alter the exposure level in post-processing, it's important to shoot at the right exposure at the scene (to maintain as much highlight/shadow detail as possible). Proper exposure in-camera will make post-processing much easier.

If shooting film -- which this image appears to be (but the 'film-look' could easily  be reproduced digitally through post-processing of a Raw file) -- you'll already get a lower contrast/saturation than digital cameras tend to produce.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it has a "cool" color temperature (notice it feels a bit "blue"), with a slight fade and higher than normal contrast (notice the black coat, hard to see any detail or folds). You could achieve this "style" through basic image editing tools.

Comment: I don't know that it's higher than normal contrast.  I'd say it's just underexposed - which explains the lack of detail in the blacks and the lack of whites - the snow and other "white" objects are grey.

Comment: I think the lack of detail is due to the contrast. Some parts of the photo are as high as `efefef`, leading me to think it's not necessarily underexposed too much. There's a high peak around the lower "light" range - a histogram of image help to visualize it a bit. It feels like it's "compressed" around this range. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/s9ag006zr363i21/2016-02-11%20at%204.55%20PM.png

Comment: @Jason Generally when there is that much snow in the frame you want some of it, but far from all of it, to be blown out. Snow is supposed to be white, not grey.

Answer (score 0):

Coud be split toned. Where the shadows are adjusted towards blue but mid tones and highlights are normal or even adjusted towards yellow or orange.